# How to get cellular carrier List from my iphone app assign one from them manually from application itself

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there a way  may be using private APIs to obtain the complete list of available Cellular networks and assign one manually from my application itself.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

### No.

Apple is very protective of that kind of thing - an app can't manually assign either a cellular or wireless network for the device to connect to. There is a special chip in the device that handles cellular connections, and only the user can control WiFi connections.

Comment: So you are saying using private APIs also its not possible.

Comment: @Baidyanath: A list of available cellular networks doesn't even *exist*. Cell phones don't work that way.

Comment: @duskwuff when you go to settings and do manual search you will get the list of available cellular networks. And you can select one from them manually too.  As I know all cell phone have this feature to select network automatic or manually

Comment: @Baidyanath Duskwuff is talking about *cellular* networks - 3G, LTE, that kind of stuff. I think you're talking about WiFi networks. There isn't a way to get a list of either.

Comment: @Undo no no I am talking about list of Cellular networks. like Suppose you are in roaming and by default At&T is selected but you want to switch to T-mobile or some other network.So in that case you can do a manual search and assign network manually.Hope now you got my point.

Comment: @Baidyanath Nope, there is no way to do that. Is your phone jailbroken?

Comment: @Undo No its not jailBroken .Also do you know how to add Private Frameworks to my existing Application. You know any demo app doing so. Actually I got some Private frameworks but I dont understand how to use them. I added those Frames to my app in normal way but the are not working.

Comment: @Baidyanath Unfortunately, I don't have any knowledge in the use of private frameworks. Note that using private frameworks that get around a limitation Apple has made will get your app rejected from the App Store.